# How to install the command "cargo set-version"?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, subcommand

I'm trying to run a script that requires the `cargo` subcommand `cargo set-version --workspace --bump="${2:-}"`.

How do I install it?

Google results only returned `cargo install set-cargo-version` but that is actually a different crate, not the one I need here, as I found out after installing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching for `set-version` on cargo.io I discovered that the crate [`cargo-edit`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-edit) installs the subcommand `cargo set-version`.

Installation works as follows:

```sh
cargo install cargo-edit
```

As @Shirshak55 mentioned: `cargo-edit` provides `cargo add`, `cargo rm`, `cargo upgrade`, `cargo set-version`

Comment: To add more info, cargo-edit provides `cargo add`
`cargo rm`
`cargo upgrade`
`cargo set-version`. Cargo now supports cargo add in latest version, so that package might not that much helpful in future :) Also, this might be helpful https://github.com/killercup/cargo-edit/issues/700